# How to print out "-E" in bash echo?

Tags: bash, echo

I want to execute echo and get an output like:

```
$ export EVAR="-E"
$ echo "$EVAR"
-E
```

I have stored "-E" in a bash variable, say `$EVAR`. If I execute `echo $EVAR`, echo will print out nothing. Perhaps it thinks $EVAR is an argument -E. Quoting `$EVAR` inside double quote marks doesn't work either.

How can I print it out?

**NOTE**: I imagine there could be a solution which is ignorant on the content of `$EVAR` - with no analysis on the content of $EVAR, a command like `echo some-arg $EVAR`. Is that possible? Or should I only turn to a workround like `printf`?

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "$EVAR"`...

Comment: Related: [Why is printf better than echo](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). Everything you ever wanted to know about echo.

Comment: For an echo-only solution, would you be ok if the output always had a blank line first, followed by the contents of `$EVAR`?

Comment: @user454038 would you please give the solution?

Comment: `printf` isn't a workaround; it's the only method of printing variables you should be using, period.  Skip `echo`.  See "Why is printf better than echo" as linked above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use tricks:

```
echo " $EVAR"
echo  -e "\055E"
echo $'\055E'
```

But as I said: those are tricks. The real solution is to use printf always:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$EVAR"
-E
```

Answer (score 1):

Per request, if you are fine with output being preceded with a blank line, test this solution yourself, on command line:

```
$ export EVAR="-E"
$ echo -e "\n$EVAR"

-E
```

- original `echo "$EVAR"` gives nothing because, as you suspected, it sees `-E` as a recognized option of `echo` command.. `man echo` says:  `-E     disable interpretation of backslash escapes (default)`
- so we precede it with a whitespace character, in this case a new line
- but you cannot directly `"\n"`, so use `-e` to interpret `"\n"`
- of course this means if you still absolutely have the original `$EVAR`, you have to do something else to the output to remove the first blank line we have now introduced

Answer (score 1):

use `printf` as mentioned, or enable `shopt xpg_echo` which gives you a *close* to standard `echo`:

```
echo 'hi\nthere'
```

---

```
hi
there
```

but it still won't handle a `-E` argument correctly. so you can write your own little standards compliant `echo` like:

```
echo()
    case  ${IFS- }  in
    (\ *) printf %b\\n "$*";;
    (*)   IFS=\ $IFS
          printf %b\\n "$*"
          IFS=${IFS#?}
    esac
```

...which will afterward *mostly* conform to a Single Unix Spec `echo` in every way *(except that a `bash` `printf` also breaks with the standard in handling `\[num]{1,3}` octals for `%b`)*.

...and so...

```
echo -E
```

---

```
-E
```

Answer (score 0):

There's always

```
echo -e "\x2DE"
```

With \x2D being the hexadecimal code for "-".  The "E" is simply appended afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
$ EVAR="-E"
$ printf "%s\n" ${EVAR}
-E
```